# .NETCORE Middleware Read the Body value from the POST entered by a user in Postman AND Validate a particular value (To:) before sent

Tags: email, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I am using a .NET CORE **API** application with **Middleware** but I need the Post to read the individual values from the Body in Postman AND have the Middleware *Validate a particular value in the Body*, for example, the (To:) of an email; and, if it meets whatever criteria I would like to **(POST)** send the email on to the intended recipient (To:) **without a** database.

This is what my code looks like so far

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body, encoding: Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false, bufferSize: bufferSize, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            //Do something



            ////From test
            if (evaluate.IsSenderFromConfiguration() == true)
              {
                 message.From = From;

              }

             message.To = new List<MailboxAddress> { new MailboxAddress("mail@mail.com")};
             message.Subject = "Message From  Create Middleware";
             message.HtmlBody = "This is just a test of Middleware  ";
             await SendEmailAsync(message);

            httpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(body);
        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);

    }
```

Here is the Post from the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Email email)
    {
        var message = new Email(_message.From, _message.To, _message.Subject, _message.HtmlBody);

        if (message == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(message);
    }
```

Right now I just have what I did in the Get to send the email.  How can I have it to where the properties **message.To**, message.From, etc. can be set by the User/Me in Postman and if the value in message.To is valid send the email?

I think there is a way to use the httpContext.Request.Body somehow, but I don't know how in .NET Core to set each individual value separately outside of the Middleware class.

To clarify:  My Post Controller DOES NOT WORK FOR FORM VALIDATION  The Middleware should be doing the work and then passing it to the controller once validated.  That is where I need the assistance for the Middleware class.

Answer (score 0):

use [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)

also use in middleware like below:

```
services.AddMvc(setup => {
      //...mvc setup...
    }).AddFluentValidation();
```